# Wordpress Drop-down menu not clickable on mobile

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am buiding a site using WordPress (4.9.8) with SHOPISLE theme.
However I am facing a problem here, I have added one dropdown menu in my Primary menu. I noticed that the dropdown menu clicks are not working on mobile view.

2nd menu has a dropdown, when clicked on text "Categories" on mobile view, the menu closes. Right now I have made it non-clickable. Can it be made to open dropdown when clicked on Text "Categories"?

Working fine on Desktop.

Thanks,
Jitendra Sawant

The page I need help with: http://jitendravertex.byethost13.com/

Comment: check the url and Its working fine what is the issue share your code.

Comment: 2nd menu has a dropdown, when clicked on text "Categories", the menu closes. Can it be made to op[en dropdown when clicked on Text "Categories"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown menu is opened when you click on the caret on the right. If you want this behaviour in the whole Categories link you should edit the menu template file in your child theme.